# Escaping inserted characters in Razor View with MvcHtmlString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The following code is being used to insert html into a Razor view.

When rendered in the page the white space, apostrophe's, and other characters are rendered as squares.

```
  @{

    string s = @Model.InnerHtml;

}
@MvcHtmlString.Create(s);
```

---

Sample of rendered: 
`May�s meeting will highlight two speakers.�`

What can I do to be sure all characters are converted to properly readable characters?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not an "escaping" issue, but rather a character encoding issue. Chance are, whatever you're loading your text from is not using the same character encoding as what your web page is telling the browser to use. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Comment: Yes that is it - Thanks. I changed the source HTML (from MS Word) to encode html as UTF-8 now renderes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an "escaping" issue, but rather a character encoding issue. Chance are, whatever you're loading your text from is not using the same character encoding as what your web page is telling the browser to use.

If the browser is using UTF-8, for example, then you should ensure that the source content is being saved using UTF-8 encoding.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML